# How to find lines that contain 3 specific characters?

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

Is there a way to remove lines that contain three specific characters?

For example the characters should be U S E

So for these lines, it should just remove USER AND UDES:

```
USER
USAD
UDES
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to "*find lines*" or "*remove*" them? You seem to contradict yourself in what you're attempting to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*U)(?=.*S)(?=.*E).+\R?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Match case*
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(?=         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    U           # letter uppercase U
)           # end lookahead
(?=.*S)     # same as above for letter S
(?=.*E)     # same as above for letter E
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
\R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]